# cosmosdb changefeed: see what changed

Tags: c#, .net, azure-cosmosdb

I have changefeed up and running which works fine. If document is changed then I have an event in my changefeed where I have current value of document.

Question, is it possible to have previous value of document as well in order to compare and see what was changed exactly ?

Example: I need to detect whether order status was changed and then fire an event.
as I have only current value of document the there is nothing to compare with and see if status was changed.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you want to check the difference with two type of feed, older and new.
i would think to memoryze almost 3 type of the same feed ID with different revision in the database..the 4th will be delete from db when they reach the number of 3
So you could revert the new feed with the older if you want also you can do the compare with previous version..

Comment: Yes, I want to see difference betwen new and previous version of document.
I don't get what you mean with memorizing 3 type of feeds. 
The only solution which came to my mind is to store each version of document in separate container and then compare current version with the latest one I have in my history container.